# Inverse of the sum of matrix and its tranpose

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is there some sort of identity or relation for getting the inverse of sum of a matrix and its transpose?
Suppose I have a matrix **A** which is  not symmetric and I want to get:

$$
B = (A + A^T)^{-1}
$$

It would have been easier if $A$ is symmetric but I want to generalize some calculations to include directed networks.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want the inverse?

Comment: Well $\mathbf{A + A^T}$ *is* symmetric, so if you have some optimal algorithm for the inversion of symmetric matrices use that.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I need it for further calculations. I was hoping to get an expansion or approximation in terms of inverse of A.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, thank you. But  I need this for analytical solution or possibly an approximation.

Comment: Do you know that $A+A^T$ is invertible in the first place?